# Нужно написать программу, для вычисления

Tags: c#

Есть форма, в которой находятся 3 textbox'a , 6 radioButton'ов и 1 button.
Порядок действий такой:

1. В textBox1 нужно ввести любое целое число.
2. Каждый radioButton должен содержать по 2 значения (у каждого radioButton'a - своё), которое нужно выбрать. (Например у radioButton1 первое 50, второе 80; у radioButton2 первое 150, второе 240; у radioButton3 первое 300, второе 720 и т.д. в порядке возрастания).
3. При нажатии на button, введенное в textBox1 значение должно умножиться отдельно(!) на каждое значение выбранного RadioButton'a, и должно отдельно вывести одно в textBox2, другое в textBox3.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что Вы уже написали, что не получается?

Comment: Вопрос написал :) задание скопипастил :)

Comment: Как-то сумбурно. Дайте код хотя бы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int[,] idValue1 = new int[6, 1];//Сюда присвой значение номерРадиоБотона-Число1
    int[,] idValue2 = new int[6, 1];//А сюда номерРадиоБотона-Число2
    int first, second;//Числа которые нужно вывести на текстбокс в конце
    RadioButton[] radioButtons = new RadioButton[6];
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int fromUser = Convert.ToInt32 (textbox1.Text);//Получание числа введенное пользователем
        for (int i = 0; i < radioButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            if (radioButtons[i].Checked)//если выбран считаем значения
            {
                 first = idValue1[i, 0] * fromUser;
                 second = idValue2[i, 0] * fromUser;
            }

        }
        texbox2.Text = first;//и выводим их
        textbox3.Text = second;
    }
```